# SQL many-to-many, how to check criteria on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In many-to-many table, how to find ID where all criteria are matched, but maybe one row matches one criterion and another row matches another criterion?

For example, let's say I have a table that maps shopping carts to products, and another table where the products are defined.

How can I find a shopping cart that has at least one one match for every criterion?

Criteria could be, for example, `product.category like '%fruit%'`, `product.category like '%vegetable%'`, etc.

Ultimately I want to get back a `shopping cart ID` (could be all of them, but in my specific case I am happy to get any matching ID) that has at least one of each match in it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your schema, your data and what you'd like to get back?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming a table named cart_per_product with fields cart,product, and a table named product with fields product,category.

```
select cart from cart_per_product c
where exists 
(
    select 1 from product p1 where p1.product=c.product and p1.category like N'%fruit%'
)
and exists 
(
    select 1 from product p2 where p2.product=c.product and p2.category like N'%vegetable%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ANY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/some-any-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operators combined with outer joins. A [simple sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76046/5) on a M:N relation:

```
select p.name
  from products p
 where id_product = ALL    -- all operator 
 (  select pc.id_product
     from categories c 
     left outer join product_category pc on pc.id_product = p.id_product and
                                          pc.id_category = c.id_category
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can figure out the column names

```
select c.id 
from cart c
join product p 
  on c.pID = p.ID 
group by c.id 
having count(distinct p.catID) = (select count(distinct p.catID) from product)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic approach that possibly isn't the most efficient:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(case when <match condition> then 1 end)
            over (partition by cartid) as matches
    from <cart inner join products ...>
)
select * from data
where matches > 0;
```